# i need start my program how administrator - Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to write my software so that need administrator rights. Because it has to create files and be able to delete them. i need make inno execute my program how administrator

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Inno Setup ISS file you can use

PrivilegesRequired=admin

Note this must go in the [Setup] section.

Comment: The question is duplicate. So do not post a duplicate answer.